# Looping same program for different data files

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

For the following program, I am trying to save time copying and pasting tons of code. I would like this program to plot using the data file 19_6.txt and aux.19_6, and then continue by plotting the files with 11,12,20,28,27, and 18 in 19's place with the same code and onto the same plot. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datasim19 = loadtxt("/home/19_6.txt")                         
data19 = loadtxt("/home/aux.19_6")                         

no1=1
no2=2
no3=3
no4=4
no5=5

no7=7
no8=8
no9=9
no10=10

simrecno1inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no1)[0]
simrecno2inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no2)[0]
simrecno3inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no3)[0]
simrecno4inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no4)[0]
simrecno5inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no5)[0]

simrecno7inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no7)[0]
simrecno8inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no8)[0]
simrecno9inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no9)[0]
simrecno10inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no10)[0]


recno1inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no1)[0]
recno2inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no2)[0]
recno3inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no3)[0]
recno4inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no4)[0]
recno5inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no5)[0]

recno7inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no7)[0]
recno8inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no8)[0]
recno9inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no9)[0]
recno10inds19 = nonzero(data19[:,1]==no10)[0]



q1sim19 = qsim19[simrecno1inds19]
q2sim19 = qsim19[simrecno2inds19]
q3sim19 = qsim19[simrecno3inds19]
q4sim19 = qsim19[simrecno4inds19]
q5sim19 = qsim19[simrecno5inds19]

q7sim19 = qsim19[simrecno7inds19]
q8sim19 = qsim19[simrecno8inds19]
q9sim19 = qsim19[simrecno9inds19]
q10sim19 = qsim19[simrecno10inds19]

q1_19 = q19[recno1inds19]
q2_19 = q19[recno2inds19]
q3_19 = q19[recno3inds19]
q4_19 = q19[recno4inds19]
q5_19 = q19[recno5inds19]

q7_19 = q19[recno7inds19]
q8_19 = q19[recno8inds19]
q9_19 = q19[recno9inds19]
q10_19 = q19[recno10inds19]

sumq1sim19 = sum(q1sim19)
sumq2sim19 = sum(q2sim19)
sumq3sim19 = sum(q3sim19)
sumq4sim19 = sum(q4sim19)
sumq5sim19 = sum(q5sim19)

sumq7sim19 = sum(q7sim19)
sumq8sim19 = sum(q8sim19)
sumq9sim19 = sum(q9sim19)
sumq10sim19 = sum(q10sim19)

sumq1_19 = sum(q1_19)
sumq2_19 = sum(q2_19)
sumq3_19 = sum(q3_19)
sumq4_19 = sum(q4_19)
sumq5_19 = sum(q5_19)

sumq7_19 = sum(q7_19)
sumq8_19 = sum(q8_19)
sumq9_19 = sum(q9_19)
sumq10_19 = sum(q10_19)


xsim = [no1, no2, no3, no4, no5, no7, no8, no9, no10]
ysim = [sumq1sim_19, sumq2sim_19, sumq3sim_19, sumq4sim_19, sumq5sim_19, sumq7sim_19, sumq8sim_19, sumq9sim_19, sumq10sim_19]

x = [no1, no2, no3, no4, no5,no7, no8, no9, no10]
y = [sumq1_19, sumq2_19, sumq3_19, sumq4_19, sumq5_19, sumq7_19, sumq8_19, sumq9_19, sumq10_19]

plt.plot(x,log(y),'b',label='Data')
plt.plot(xsim,log(ysim),'r',label='Simulation')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Data vs. Simulation')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why can't you wrap it in a `for` loop iterating over `num` from the list `['11','12,'20','28','27','18']` and use `loadtxt("/home/%s_6.txt"%num)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tip: when you find yourself using lots of variables called n1, n2, n3 etc. you should probably use lists, dictionaries or other such containers, and loops instead.

For example, try replacing the following code:

```
simrecno1inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no1)[0]
simrecno2inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no2)[0]
simrecno3inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no3)[0]
simrecno4inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no4)[0]
simrecno5inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no5)[0]

simrecno7inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no7)[0]
simrecno8inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no8)[0]
simrecno9inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no9)[0]
simrecno10inds19 = nonzero(datasim19[:,1]==no10)[0]
```

With this:

```
simrecinds19 = [nonzero(datasim19[:,1] == i)[0] for i in range(1, 11)]
```

Then you can use `simrecinds19[0]` instead of `simrecno1inds19`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
nList = [19,11,12,20,28,27,18]

for n in nList:
    file1 = "/home/" + str(n) + "_6.txt"
    file2 = "/home/aux." + str(n) + "_6"

    datasim19 = loadtxt(file1)                         
    data19 = loadtxt(file2)  

    # do the rest of the plotting
```

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly reduce the size of this script. I'm not quite sure where `qsim19` and `qsim` come from, but take a look:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for index in [19, 11, 12, 20, 28, 27, 18]:
    datasim = loadtxt("/home/%i_6.txt"%index)                         
    data = loadtxt("/home/aux.%i_6"%index)                         

    nos = range(1, 6) + range(7, 11)

    simrecno = [np.nonzero(datasim[:,1] == n)[0] for n in nos]
    recno = [np.nonzero(data[:,1] == n)[0] for n in nos]

    qsim = [qsim[simrecno_i] for simrecno_i in simrecno]
    q = [q[recno_i] for recno_i in recno]

    sumqsim = [sum(qsim_i) for qsim_i in qsim]
    sumq = [sum(q_i) for q_i in q]

    xsim = nos
    ysim = sumqsim

    x = nos
    y = sumq

    plt.plot(x, log(y), 'b', label='Data')
    plt.plot(xsim, log(ysim), 'r', label='Simulation')
    plt.legend()
    plt.title('Data vs. Simulation')
    plt.show()
```